# is ML Flow Pytorch Lightning autologging supposed to automatically log metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, databricks, mlflow, pytorch-lightning

I am attempting to use MLflow to log a pytorch lightning model to experiments in Databricks. Accoring to the [documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#automatic-logging), it seems like metrics like training and validation loss are supposed to be logged automatically without having to call self.log within the model. However, the metrics page is blank if I do not explicitly log anything within the model. However, I see all of my logged metrics in the experiments page when I do explicitly log things. My question is if I am missing anything. The documentation really makes it seem like certain metrics are logged automatically. How come MLflow does not log these metrics automatically?

Note: I do in fact see the params of the model automatically, just not the metrics without logging them. My code looks something like this:

```
mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name = "path_to_databricks_experiment")
mlflow.autolog(log_input_examples = True)
mlflow.pytorch.autolog(log_every_n_epoch=1, log_models=True)

trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs = 2, default_root_dir="path_to_databricks_experiment", log_every_n_steps=1)

with mlflow.start_run():
    trainer.fit(model, data_module)
```

It is weird that I am getting params logged automatically but not metrics.

Comment: Welcome to SO; you seem to ask two different questions, in your title and the body. Please edit & update to clarify **exactly** is your issue and your question are.